Why has my dehumidifier stopped producing water?
I have a Santa Fe Classic dehumidifier in basement. I've changed filters regularly for many years. That’s it. Now it does not seem to dehumidify. I ran it for an hour on humid day, nothing. I’d like to repair myself. I’ve checked on line, YouTube, etc., nothing well addresses maintenance and repair. The machines are about 3k and I prefer to fix than rebuy.

Also related: Is it possible to recharge a dehumidifier

Short answer: Dehumidifiers are built like garbage and rarely last more than a very few years before they lose their refrigerant. After that they're not worth repairing due to complexity and the likelihood of recurring failure. They're the only thing that I buy extended warranties for. I'm on my fourth one in the last 15 years or so, and I've had three of them replaced or repaired before chucking them on the recycling heap. It's a crime.

I'm on my third in about 20 years, so only slightly better than @isherwood. But I don't use mine in summer. I've replaced a fan motor (it was the same as a desk fan I had) but that one eventually lost its refrigerant. The next leaked compressor oil. In what currency was it 3k, because that sounds very expensive in any I'm familiar with?

I have never before seen a $3000 dehumidifier for a residential basement.
Most of the canned wisdom you'll get here are from people, like me, who have $300 (or less) dehumidifiers.  They typically last 4 or 5 years.   You can be lucky or unlucky with that. When it fails you buy a new one.  They are not built to be repairable, and when the cooling circuit leaks or goes bad, the tools and skills required to fix it are specialized, you have to call an A/C or fridge person whose fees will be at least the price of a new dehumidifier.
How do you diagnose and repair a $3000 one?   I would start by calling the manufacturer, and if this thing is really that special, a local Fridge repair perosn.
But my advice is to buy a the best machine you can find for $300.   Or if your basement is huge or just crazy wet, try to eliminate the source of wetness, and/or buy two of the best machines you can find for $300.   Ya you'll have to replace them from time to time. By the time you've spent $3000 it'll be your grandchildrens' problem.

In any case, if in the US or many other countries, your service/repair choice is to call someone with the proper licenses to handle refrigerants, in the present era. Or take a course (perhaps several...) to become such a person. They ain't DIY.
